# Listing all files that require/import a specific file

Tags: node.js, regex, refactoring, yarn-workspaces

I have a `utilities.js` file which I would like to move out into it's own yarn package.

Currently there are a lot of files which require `utilities.js` through a relative path, some examples are

```
const utils = require('../../../utilities/utilities');
const utilities = require('../../../../../utilities/utilities.js')
const utils = require('./utilities.js')
import { someFunction } from '../../../utilities/utilities.js'
```

I'm looking for a solution to rename all of the require/imports statements to `@myUtilities`

I've attempted to use VSCodes find feature with a regex match but I've fallen short or included some undesired matches.

The best pattern I've been able to come up with is

```
\'(..?\/)*(\/)?utilities(\/utilities)?(.js)?\'
```

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Can't you just do a Find in All folders of your *own code* (not in node_modules) for `utilities.js`? That should find all instances regardless of the path.

Comment: I'm looking to replace everything, including the `../../../`, so unfortunately that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
(?:import|require).*?(['"].*utilities(\/utilities)?(.js)?['"])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GM7HpV/2)

Comment: I should've mentioned VSCode uses the JS for regex, also the demo seems to capture more than what is in the single quotes

Comment: @DimitrijeM i made some changes you can look into it.

Comment: The example is still capturing more than required, I only need the text within and including the single quotes and  eg. `'../../../utilities/utilities'`

Comment: @DimitrijeM just check the groups not the complete match.In groups i have captured what you want.